# Database design for equipment maintenance management application

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am designing a database for a maintenance management application in medical equipment (hospital equipment). I have some questions about the design of this model. Actually, I've already modeled the database schema, but I'm not sure if this modeling is optimal. So I would ask for some advice for those whose expertise is in the field, as I am not.

Just to contextualize, in my application there are hospitals, where each hospital has several sectors, and each sector has several equipments (modeling represented in red in the figure). In addition, there is a contract that specifies which equipment is covered for maintenance. That is, as not all equipment is covered by the contract, the maintenance team should only perform maintenance on the equipment that is in the contract.

Considered my questions:

- Would this modeling be appropriate for this problem? Is there any problem or any more suitable way for this?
- If I'm going to do a query on all the equipment that belongs to a particular hospital and a contract, how would I do that? Can I do it in this schema?
- Regarding the sector entity, should I leave the sector as an entity (as illustrated in figure) or should I insert an attribute in the equipment table and delete the sector table?

[My database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1BAg.png)

I hope these questions are appropriate for the Stackoverflow criteria. I thank you for any help and support in clearing up these questions. Thank you very much.

Sincerely, Renan Fonteles.

Comment: Given your description, the model in your diagram looks workable - I don't see any glaring problems with it, at least.  What is the purpose of the "sector" subdivision of a hospital?  To answer your questions about querying, though - yes, you can.  You'll have a foreign key on each piece of equipment that that indicates which maintenance contract covers it (leave it NULL if there's no contract) and another foreign key linking equipment to either sector (and sector back to hospital) or from equipment to hospital directly, and the query will be based on those keys.

Comment: Hello Brian, thank you for replying. Regarding the "sector", it is important that we track where the equipment is located inside the hospital, that is, in which sector it is located. It may change throughout time. But I'm not sure if this should be in a table or as an equpiment's attribute though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given our chat in the comments section, here's how I'd do what you describe in SQL Server:

```
Location
    ID
    Address
    City
    etc.

Client
    ID
    Location_ID    FK to Location.ID
    Name

Contract
    ID
    Client_ID      FK to Client.ID
    Name

Hospital
    ID
    Location_ID    FK to Location.ID
    Name

Sector
    ID
    Description

Equipment
    ID
    Sector_ID
    Hospital_ID
    Contract_ID
    Serial_Number
    Description
    etc.

Observation
    ID
    Equipment_ID
    Observation_Date
    Observation_Details
```

I know the Location and Observation tables are new to the design - Location is a table I factored out since multiple entities have location information, and Observation seemed like a logical extension.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm always amused when someone down-votes an answer without explaining the reason for the down-vote.  Amused, and saddened by the inherent cowardice of that act.

Comment: Hello Brian! Sorry for the late reply. I didn't understand the need for Location. I've been thinking, and I concluded that sector does not need a table. It can be just an attribute of equipment. This will make the scheme simpler. In that case, I will have Contract relationship to Equipment in order to inform which equipments are under a maintenance contract, as in Hospital, I will have the information of all equipment present in a specific hospital. Do you think it is workable to have both entities Hospital and Contract? Or this is not a good way of modeling this? Once again, thank you.

Comment: The purpose of the Location table was to avoid storing the same address in multiple locations.  I tend to normalize that out, but I'm in the minority there.

Comment: Regarding Hospital and Contract entities - they're independent of each other, correct?  If so, then it's not just "workable" to have both entities, it's necessary.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think you answered pretty much all my questions. Thank you again Brian. I would vote up the answer, but I am not allowed to.

Comment: Glad I could help - feel free to ping me if you have any other questions about this.